# Cyles. How can I add a sky to my scene?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing, world

Well, I'm doing a project and I keep trying to add in a sky but It never works and I don't know whats wrong. [image]

Comment: The way to add a sky depends in part upon which type of rendering engine you are using. If you're using the Blender Internal renderer, then the basic  technique is to add a quarter of a very large sphere to the scene, and decorate it to represent the sky. If you're iusing the cycles rendering engine, then the sky is set up through the World properties context tab in the properties editor windwo.

Comment: *Properties Window > Render tab > Film* uncheck *Transparent* option. Also switch viewport from orthographic views to perspective.

Answer (score 2):

Although I am not exactly sure, I see a square tile pattern behind the ground mesh object. I have never used this feature myself but it seems you have the transparent background feature on. To turn it off go into the properties panel and go to the output section where you choose what format you want to export in, you might have it set as a png, and as far as i know if you have it set as a png and (you'll have to double check if you try and fail as i might be missing a detail) underneath in the FILM section a transpartent option is activated you will make your background transparent or "truly invisible" to the camera. Hope that helps.

Comment: I just checked and it does not matter in what format you have it, as long as you have that transparent check box on it will be invisible, all you have to do is turn it off.

Answer (score 1):

In the *Properties Window > Render tab > Film* uncheck *Transparent* option.

Also make sure to switch viewport from orthographic views to perspective